# Разработайте тип данных, характеризующий операции над строками

Tags: haskell

**Определим следующий набор операций над строками:**

- Очистка: удаление всех символов из строки
- Удаление: удаление всех вхождений указанного символа
- Замена: замена всех вхождений одного символа на другой
- Добавление: добавление в начало строки указанного символа

Разработайте тип данных, характеризующий операции над строками. 
*Определите следующие функции:*

1) **process**, получающая в качестве аргумента действие и строку и возвращающая строку, модифицированную в соответствие с указанным действием.

2) **processAll**, аналогичная предыдущей, но получающая список действий и выполняющая их по порядку.

3) **deleteAll**, принимающая две строки и удаляющей из второй строки все символы первой. При реализации обязательно использовать функцию processAll.

Comment: @Dimys1, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: я уже нашел ответ на другом форуме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data StrAction = StrClear | StrDelete Char | StrReplace Char Char | StrAdd Char deriving (Eq,Show)

process :: String -> StrAction -> String
process s (StrClear) = []
process [] (StrDelete _) = []
process (s:ss) (StrDelete c) = if (s == c) then process ss (StrDelete c) else s : process ss (StrDelete c)
process [] (StrReplace _ _) = []
process (s:ss) (StrReplace w f) = if (s == w) then f : (process ss (StrReplace w f)) else s : (process ss (StrReplace w f)) 
process s (StrAdd x) = x : s

processAll :: [StrAction] -> String -> String
processAll [] x = x
processAll (p:ps) x = processAll ps (process x p)

deleteAll :: String -> String -> String
deleteAll s d = processAll (map StrDelete d) s
```